How can i get user id from nextjs using next-auth.js in server side?
I want to access the user id on my server-side in the next js 14
i want how to get user id from next-auth in server side component when i add import { getServerSession } from "next-auth"; this then i get the error like  Module '"next-auth"' has no exported member 'getServerSession'. Did you mean to use 'import getServerSession from "next-auth"' instead?
